# Same size in MasterPane in ZedGraph

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, zedgraph

I'm plotting some graphs with MasterPane, with x axis synchronized. The problem is when de size (number of character) os the units in the y axis are different. The problem is that the size of plot area changes.
Look the picture. The plot area do not have the same length.
How can I fix this?

Ps. I'm using Visual Studio c#

Thanks.

[image: ZedGraph]

Answer (score 0):

I also bumped into this problem a few weeks ago and spent hours to solve this but finally got the solution. You just need to follow the chart settings on the following wiki link. You can then change the number of panes (in your case its 2) and graphic options (colors etc.) Hope this helps.

[Stack zedgraph charts vertically aligned in a single column](http://zedgraph.dariowiz.com/indexd1a6.html?title=Stack_charts_vertically_and_align_the_X_axes)